# Java constructor confusion, what goes where?

Tags: java, constructor

Unsure as to what should be placed into the constructor and what should just be a field, I notice that you can add things to be initialized without them having to be in the constructor. Here are two examples, that I'm just unsure as to which is best to use and the reasons behind it.

Example 1:

```
public class PurchaseOrder {
    private String date;
    private String customerID;
    private String productCode;
    private int quantity;
    private int discountRate;
    private int pricePerUnit;
    private CustomerDetails customer; // The part that I'm changing

    public PurchaseOrder(OrderDate date, String id,
            Product product, int quantity) {
        this.discountRate = customer.getDiscountRate();
        this.date = date.getDate();
        this.customerID = customer.getCustomerID();
        this.productCode = product.getProductCode();
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.pricePerUnit = product.getPricePerUnit();
    }
```

Example 2:

```
public class PurchaseOrder {
    private String date;
    private String customerID;
    private String productCode;
    private int quantity;
    private int discountRate;
    private int pricePerUnit;
    public PurchaseOrder(OrderDate date, CustomerDetails customer,
            Product product, int quantity) {
        this.discountRate = customer.getDiscountRate();
        this.date = date.getDate();
        this.customerID = customer.getCustomerID();
        this.productCode = product.getProductCode();
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.pricePerUnit = product.getPricePerUnit();
    }
```

Notice that I can put the CustomerDetails customer in the constructor or just have it as a variable. If it's in the constructor it means that if an object is made of this class it must also contain information of CustomerDetails. But both work fine. What's the best option and reason for it?

Comment: How is ```CustomerDetails customer``` being instantiated in the first example?

Comment: Your first example is going to give you a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: what do you mean? doesn't CustomerDetails customer make "customer" the object, thus it has been instantiated?

Comment: @user3667111 No. That's C++. In Java, `CustomerDetails customer` is the same as `CustomerDetails customer = null;`

Comment: No.  You have declared a variable that can hold a reference to a CustomerDetails object, but no object reference has been put there.  If you wanted to create a new one to put there, you need `CustomerDetails customer = new CustomerDetails();` (assuming it has an empty constructor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you pass in the constructor as a parameter has already been made in another class as an object such as

```
CustomerDetails customerInConstructor = new CustomerDetails();
```

Then you could go

```
PurchaseOrder purchase = new PurchaseOrder(customerInConstructor, otherParameters)
```

If you don't wanna pass in an object you made from a previous class and instead make a new one for another class you could just make a variable for it like shown in the first example.

```
private CustomerDetails customer;
```

Constructors are primarily ways to take variables from other classes like your main class and use those variables to make methods that affect them or add things to them. I hope I kinda helped, have a good day!

Comment: Ahh okay, so in my case I only want to use the customer object so I can use the methods within the CustomerDetails class. But I don't actually want to pass in an object to this class. So my first example would be best? is this considered good practice?

Comment: Yeah, the first example would be best because you don't need to pass it in like you said. Making it a variable would be better practice because than you can use the classes methods, but be sure to pass in the right parameters when you make the object from the class, CustomerDetails, and when you call its methods. Good luck and have fun!